# Getting a Logged in Users Role in Blazor Server App

Tags: c#, blazor

I am pretty new to Blazor and have figured out how to list all the users in my database, but cannot seem to figure out how to view the role of the user so I can output to a table, as well as adding a user to that role when I save.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Maybe show the relevant parts where your setting up the UserManager and RoleManager in `program.cs`

Comment: Pretty sure you just answered my question. Let me see what I can do from here

Answer (score 1):

I know that I am too late but maybe this can help you or someone else

**Get a list of users with their assigned role**

```cs
public Task<List<UserProfileDto>> GetAllAsync()
{
    var result = _context.Users
        .Join(_context.UserRoles, u => u.Id, r => r.UserId, (u, r) => new { u, r })
        .Join(_context.Roles, a => a.r.RoleId, rt => rt.Id, (a, rt) => new UserProfileDto
        {
            Id = a.u.Id,
            Email = a.u.Email,
            Phone = a.u.PhoneNumber,
            Username = a.u.UserName,
            IsActive = a.u.IsActive,
            LockoutEnd = a.u.LockoutEnd,
            Rolename = rt.Name
        }).ToListAsync();

        return result;
}
```

**Check logged in user role on a component (.razor)**

```cs
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    <p>This is Admin area</p>
}


@code {
    ClaimsPrincipal User = new ClaimsPrincipal();

    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
        User = authState.User;
    }


}
```

**Check logged in user role server side**

```cs
public class DemoService
{
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authState;

    public DemoService(AuthenticationStateProvider authState)
    {
        _authState = authState;
    }

    public bool HasRole(string roleName)
    {
        var authstate = _authState.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result;
        var user = authstate.User;
        return user.IsInRole(roleName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create roles you can use this syntax

```
new AuthenticationState(
                new ClaimsPrincipal(
                    new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { 
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, m_login),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "demo_role"),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"),
                    }, "PutAppNameHere"
            )));
```

To get role list

```
public List<string> GetRoles(ClaimsPrincipal user)
{
    var userIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity;
    var claims = userIdentity.Claims;
    return claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Select(_ => _.Value).ToList();
}
```

Find a full functionnal example on how to handle authentication and localization in my Github example

https://github.com/iso8859/AspNetCoreAuthMultiLang